# COM object keeps returning a stub even if I start the server application

Tags: python, win32com

I have a program with

```
 repo = win32com.client.Dispatch("EA.App").Repository
```

and that works fine all time. However, once I called that while the EA.app instance was not running I permanently get rubbish

> `<COMObject <unknown>>`

in return - until I reboot Windoze. What's that? And more importantly: how do I get around the reboot?

P.S. Right after writing I found that

```
 repo = win32com.client.Dispatch("EA.App")
```

returns

> `<COMObject EA.App>`

So, may I assume this is something with that EA.app not doing right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`win32com.client.Dispatch("EA.App")` creates a new instance of the `EA.App` COM class.

I'm assuming that connecting the COM object to the "EA.app instance" or whatever (presumably via an IPC channel) happens at creation time, so if it wasn't running, you end up with a dummy object that remains such.

Maybe the COM class has some method that would force it to rediscover the server application without having to recreate the COM object. But since recreating is easy, it's very possible that the developer thought that such a function wouldn't add enough value to the product to justify the expenses.

---

Some COM classes implement some kind of the [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern): calling `Dispatch` multiple times will use a "cached" result from the first one internally and actually return objects that are somehow "the same". If this is the case, just calling `Dispatch` again wouldn't help. In this case, check with the COM class' documentation and/or its vendor how you force the rediscovery. (E.g. there may be a way to explicitly delete the "cached" underlying object so the next `Dispatch` creates a new one.)

Comment: Thanks. It looks like I have to think over this once I slept this night :-) I'm no Windoze expert, so understanding it deep enough might take me a bit. I'll come back.

Comment: I think I grasped what you told above. Most likely it's buried in the EA.App judging from other strange things they did in there. I'll send a bug report but with no big hope, though.